# Microsoft Excel Stored Values Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that I received that is using a formula with a "Stored Values" in the formula. I have never run across this use before and I'm not sure where the values are stored and what they are. The full formula in the cell is:

='Stored Values'!C4*37.5

Is there a way I can look at what the stored values are and what formula or calculation is being done to come to those values? C4 in this worksheet is just text so I'm not sure how to access the values.

Comment: The way it is typed, "Stored Values" is another worksheet (tab). Look for hidden worksheets (tabs) that are in your workbook.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/545131/what-should-i-do-if-i-see-a-reference-in-excel-cell-formulas-to-a-sheet-that-i-c may be helpful

Comment: Stored Values this is a Sheet in your Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, that "Stored Values" in the formula references a different worksheet. This may be in a hidden worksheet, so right click on the worksheet name at the bottom of the screen then click "Unhide". This will bring up a list of worksheets which are hidden. Select the "Stored Values" worksheet, and click Ok. You should then be able to see the "Stored Values" worksheet, and look at the data you are looking for.